# Change default font in Word Office for Mac 2011

Tags: ms-office

How I can change the default font of Word Office for Mac 2011?

Comment: If you don't get an answer here, just search on default font over at http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/mac/forum/macword

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Word,

1. `File | Open`
2. Click on `Your HD`, double click `Users`, then find and double click on `[your username]` (as opposed to `Shared`).
3. Double-click `Library`.
4. Scroll down to `Application Support`, double click, and choose `Microsoft`. Select `Office`, and then find `User Templates` You should see `Normal.dot` or `Normal.dotm`.
5. Open this, and adjust *ALL* the settings you like (margins, font, spacing, you can even type in the doc to include space for where you want your name, title, date to appear on every document you create in the future!)
6. Don't forget to SAVE! Then exit.
7. Open a new doc and fill in the blanks/change your prompts and GO!

Comment: Interestingly, navigating directly to Normal.dotm in the filesystem first, opening it by double-clicking, and editing it *will not work properly* (e.g. toolbar and shortcut customization will be gone) even if the resulting file is saved as dotm. It is important to do File -> Open...

Answer (score 0):

To permanently change the font formatting for all new documents use the following procedures.

1. On the Format menu, click Font.
2. Make all of the desired changes in the Font dialog box.
3. Click Default.
4. When prompted with the following, click Yes:

   Do you want to change the default font to < list of changes>? This change will affect all new documents based on the NORMAL template.
5. Hold down the SHIFT key while clicking on the File menu, and click
   Save All.

Word will not prompt you to save the changes to the Normal.dot unless you have the option "Prompt to Save Normal template" selected on the Save tab of the Preferences dialog box (on the Tools menu, click Preferences).